# What is the first appearance of a Lich in fantasy literature?

Tags: magical-creatures, literary-analysis

What is the first appearance of a Lich in fantasy literature? I will accepts answers pointing to myths ans sagas and such as well.

Edit: For clarity, I'm asking about Liches as defined by [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lich)

> Often such a creature is the result of a transformation, as a powerful magician or king striving for eternal life uses spells or rituals to bind his intellect to his animated corpse and thereby achieve a form of immortality. Liches are depicted as being clearly cadaverous, their bodies desiccated or even completely skeletal. Liches are often depicted as holding power over hordes of lesser undead creatures, using them as soldiers and servants.

Comment: You should provide a definition of what a "Lich" was

Comment: Are you asking about the concept of an evil wizard who turns himself undead in order to live forever... or the *term* "Lich"?  If the latter, it was an archaic synonym for "corpse" that the original designers of D&D adopted in the late '70s.

Answer (score 14):

One of the candidates is Russian folcloric character of [Koschey the Deathless](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9#.D0.94.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B2.D0.BD.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.83.D1.81.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D0.B7.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5). It was formally present in written sources as far back as 12th century, but likely significantly predates that as an oral tradition.

Sources to peruse:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lich#In_religion_and_mythology)
- [TVTropes list of Liches](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OurLichesAreDifferent)

Comment: Koschei is **not** undead. He is unkillable because he has hidden his heart/vulnerablility somewhere remote and you have to destroy that to kill him.

Comment: Lich's are typically said to also have their vulnerability stored away somewhere, normally referred to as a Soul Jar, so that doesn't discount Koschei from being a lich, it adds to the idea.